# enable Button from another Screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to enable a Button from another Screen. However my code doesn't allow it. My method of changing a variable should work in normal python, right?, so why doesn't it work in kivy?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    is_enabled = BooleanProperty(False)

class Screen2(Screen):
    def disable(self):
        Screen1.is_enabled = True
        print("is enabled")

kv = Builder.load_string("""
Manager:
    Screen1:
        name: 'screen1'
    Screen2:
        name: 'screen2'

<Screen1>
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "test"
            disabled: not root.is_enabled
        Button:
            text: "switch screens"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "screen2"
                               
<Screen2>
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "switch screens"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "screen1"
        Button:
            text: "enable other button"
            on_release:
                root.disable()
 """)

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

This should run and be reproducable.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I initially left out the last two lines of code to make it even simpler. Tho now I have added them back so it is reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
class fscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def disable(self):
        self.secscreen.ids.target.disabled = False

    def button_first(self):
        print('something')    


class secscreen(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def disable(self):
        self.fscreen.ids.target.disabled = False

    def button_second(self):
        print('something') 

class theapp(App):
    def build(self):
        
        self.screenm = ScreenManager() 

        self.fscreen = fscreen()
        screen = Screen(name = "first screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.fscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(screen)

        self.secscreen = secscreen()
        screen = Screen(name = "second screen")
        screen.add_widget(self.secscreen)
        self.screenm.add_widget(seccreen)

        return self.screenm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    theapp = theapp()                                       #
    theapp.run()
```

in ur kv file `the.kv` :

```
<fscreen>
    Button: 
        id: target
        size: #whatver
        pos: #whatever
        disabled: True
        on_press: root.button_first()

    Button:
        text: 'disable second screen button'
        size: #whatver
        pos: #whatever
        on_press: root.disable()
     

<secscreen>

    Button: 
        id: target
        size: #whatver
        pos: #whatever
        disabled: True
        on_press: root.button_second()
   
    Button:
        text: 'disable first screen button'
        size: #whatver
        pos: #whatever
        on_press: root.disable()
```

And to recap if u want to disable a button from python u need to give ur button an `id` and then in ur python u use `self.ids.button.disable = False or True`  if the button is in another class u use `self.class_name.ids.Button_Name.disabled = True or False` and just to remind u a widget id is unique to its class so `id: target` of the fscreen is not `id: target` of the secscreen

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are treating `is_enabled` as a class variable, but `Properties` are instance variables (even though they are defined at the class level). And changing a `Property` at the class level actually replaces the `Property` with a simple variable and eliminates its bindings (as are created by the `kv`). The fix is to just access the `is_enabled` `Property` correctly. Try changing:

```
Screen1.is_enabled = True
```

to:

```
self.manager.get_screen("screen1").is_enabled = True
```

This code accesses the `ScreenManager` through the `manager` attribute of `Screen2`, then gets the `Screen1` instance using the `get_screen()` method of `ScreenManager`. Then the `is_enabled` can be accessed correctly as an instance variable.